# perform update operation in cascading drop list asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created 3 list e.g. Country, State, Cities. I have populated them successfully & have sent selected value to the database table.

But during `update` operation as I have fetched the values of respective columns/fields, system is unable to find the selected values except the 'Country' drop down list. As it has been populating at `page_load` and rest of two are blank because no change has made to it. And I am trying to Select the value/item selected previously (during `save/insert` operation).

I am confused how could I bind the state and cities list on the value of Country available in the dataset.

Please suggest some ways.

Thanks you!

Comment: Very broad question and no code. Those two makes less likely to get a satisfying answer. However I'm not sure if it's possible but the best option would be to use `update panel` for partial updates. Also you can save state in the `ViewState` but it's not available during `Page_Load` so you have to rebind the controls on some other event.

Comment: @Leron Thanks so much for the response.. actually, I have successfully bind all the ddl using autopost back but at this time I am confuse, and learnt this scenario using trial and error method. However I would like to know how this `update panel` could help me? thank so much!!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @NikhilG Well, I'm also learning `Web Forms` right now working on my first project using this framework. So can't get you into too much detail. Just google `asp update panel` and see what it offers. In short - you put all `ddl`s inside update panel, then then the `update panel` had a `trigger..` something option where you specify the `ID`s of your ddl. And the idea behind this is that every time you perform operation using some of your `ddl`s it will behave as if you are using plain `AJAX` or in other words - you won't lose any information on the page and will get updated only the control

Comment: That had triggered an event. This is the theory and I don't say that this is exactly how things work but I use `Update panels` in such kind of scenarios and they work fine for me. So Just google some more about this asp control and see if you can put the `ddl`s inside update panel. Ultimately I would recommend to write your own `Ajax` functions.

Comment: @Leron thanks so much again for such a nice description.. it is nice co-incidence that this web application is also my first professional project.. but I have already visited update panel (using search engine) and seriously working on it too.. sooner I will update some code for this issue. Thanks again!